# Linked server from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2008 giving 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' error

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014, linked-server

When I deployed a linked server using the `sp_addlinkedserver` and `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin` command it is giving me an error -

> 'Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "link" returned message
>   "Invalid connection string attribute".**

When the same linked server is deployed from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2014 only, it works. What is the problem and how to resolve it? I have searched for over 3 hours on google and cannot find a to the point solution for the same.